# How are Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow related?

Tags: discussion

Can I consolidate my reputation from that site to this?

It seems you are both under the same "engine", are you also owned by the same people? Are you managed by the same managers?

Last but not least: What's your business model? Is there a "for pay" section?

I see there are no advertisements, which is great! So got me wondering.

Comment: You should see ads. Are you using an ad blocker of some sort?

Comment: I don't use an ad blocker (not when on here, anyway) and, right now, I only see one FreeBSD link off to the side, and I am not even sure that is an ad.  I never see ads here.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin That's because you already have 500 reputation and more. See: [Privileges - Reduce Ads](http://superuser.com/privileges/reduced-ads)

Comment: In the future, please ask questions *about* the site on the "Meta", which is where your question ended up right now. Every site has its own Meta site, and there's one for the entire network over at [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Most visitors come from search engines and don't have accounts. They're the business model. Users with reputation provide the content they come for. So they're rewarded for that by ad removal.

Answer (score 13):

> Can I consolidate my reputation from that site to this?

No. Every Stack site carries its own reputation for your account. This is simply because you can be an expert [on cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/), but at the same time have not a single clue [about programming](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Since reputation shows how much the community trusts you and how useful your posts are, it is *not* shared and transferred between sites.

However, if you get 200 reputation on one site, all other accounts on the Stack Exchange network that are linked to this one will automatically get an "association bonus", which means you can start out with 101 reputation rather than 1. This is because we can now trust you to use the site as it was intended, and therefore unlock certain privileges.

> Are you also owned by the same people? Are you managed by the same managers?

Yes. Stack Exchange was founded after Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky created [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). Soon thereafter [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) and Super User followed. This is called the "trilogy" of initial sites. For more, see: http://stackexchange.com/about

Today, Stack Exchange comprises [a large number of sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites#oldest) that all are managed by [a core team](http://stackexchange.com/about/team) and [community moderators](http://stackexchange.com/about/moderators).

> What's your business model? Is there a "for pay" section?

No. There will never be. Stack Exchange was founded with the idea of being *free* for everyone to use.

Ads are being shown to all users, albeit with more reputation, ads will become less intrusive.

Comment: Or vice versa. I always burn the salad!

Comment: @Dennis You should definitely drop that and use jQuery instead.

Comment: `$('salad').cook().bind('burn', throwAway);` It is really great and can do all things.